# Looking for solutions for Parse error, I need to calculate based on the value of the percentage

Tags: parsing, ifs

If it is greater than 1.5 then, we multiply x2, if it is less than 1.6 then we divide by 2  =IFS(E2>1.5%/2,[E2<1.6%,*2]*C2)

Per formula above

The result should be based on the %

C2 is contract revenue
e2 is percentage

Comment: What exactly is the problem with this formula? Please provide some example inputs and what you expect vs. what you get.